# Docker returns "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string"

Tags: go, docker, virtual-machine, boot2docker, fig

I'm new to docker. I tried to launch an image with:

```
fig up -d --allow-insecure-ssl
```

But I get the following error message:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string
```

And I can't figure out how to fix it.

My `fig.yml`:

```
configrepo:
  image: docker-registry.backbasecloud.com/backbase/engage-configuration:latest
  environment:
    - SERVICE_NAME=configuration
  ports:
      - "8788:8080"

configserver:
  image: docker-registry.backbasecloud.com/backbase/engage-configserver:latest
  environment:
    SERVICE_NAME: configserver
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  links:
    - configrepo:configrepo
  dns: 172.17.42.1
```

docker version

```
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.8.2
Server API version: 1.20
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0a8c2e3
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

fig --version

```
fig 1.0.1
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I've the same error on ```docker run hello-world```.
```docker -v``` shows ```Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, [`fig`](http://www.fig.sh/) has long been migrated to **[`docker compose`](https://github.com/docker/compose)**.
Second, docker 1.6.2 is not the newest release of docker.

So before chasing that bug too much (in light of issues like [1638](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1638)):

- update to `docker compose` and docker 1.8.2
- check your entrypoint in your `docker-compose.yml`: [`true` should be `/bin/true`](https://github.com/andreagrandi/postgresql-docker/pull/2) for instance.

Comment: hi. (1) I tried with the latest version of docker, but I get the same error.

Comment: @Vovochka with `fig` or `docker compose`? And what is your `docker-compose.yml` content?